# Chrome won't install or launch

Tags: google-chrome

Same error as JadeHouse:

```
[9940:9940:0228/003228.235113:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[9940:9940:0228/003228.235232:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/robert/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[9940:9940:0228/003228.235288:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/robert/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[9940:9940:0228/003228.235313:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)] Failed to create /home/robert/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission denied (13)
[9940:9940:0228/003228.235794:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[9940:9940:0228/003228.235824:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/robert/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[9940:9940:0228/003228.235924:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1496)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
[9940:9977:0228/003228.268812:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(121)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

- `sudo killall google-chrome`   says no processes running
- `rm /home/subham/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock` says access is denied

Curiously I can choose Chrome as my default web browser but nothing will start it. google-chrome-stable in Terminal produces the failed to launch GPU process error above.

Comment: The package may be `chrome-browser` or `google-chrome-stable`, but the process probably is `chrome`. Check with `pgrep -l chrome`. Try with `pkill chrome`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
sudo chown robert:robert /home/robert/.config/google-chrome -R
```

If failed remove /home/robert/.config/google-chrome and allow it to create new configuration.
 I hope you have backup of your bookmarks.

```
sudo rm -R /home/robert/.config/google-chrome
```

relaunch google chrome.

Comment: your most welcome