# Google Chrome 81 doesn't launch after installation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I have installed Chrome browser v81 but when I'm trying to launch the browser, I'm getting below error message:

```
[22725:22742:0418/111128.075479:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[22725:22725:0418/111128.075495:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(404)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[22725:22725:0418/111128.075524:ERROR:process_singleton_lock_posix.cc(19)] readlink(/home/ewsetiawan/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[22725:22742:0418/111128.075531:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[22725:22725:0418/111128.075545:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/ewsetiawan/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[22725:22725:0418/111128.075552:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)] Failed to create /home/ewsetiawan/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock: Permission denied (13)
[22725:22725:0418/111128.075565:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(404)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[22725:22725:0418/111128.075574:ERROR:process_singleton_lock_posix.cc(19)] readlink(/home/ewsetiawan/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[22725:22725:0418/111128.075607:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1408)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't solve the problem. What to do
The browser isn't launched. How can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I would check the permissions of the contents of ~/.config/ to ensure all contents there are owned by you. If you've regularly using `sudo` when you shouldn't be, you may have changed permissions such that you've locked yourself away from your own config files.   Just a thought.

Comment: Please mention whether the previous version of Chrome worked. To address the point raised by @guiverc, `cd $HOME && find . ! -user $USER -ls` will recursively find all files **not** owned by you. The command may take some time to complete.

Comment: thank you sir problem solved i have changed permission

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after changing permissions and removing configuration directory

```
sudo chown ewsetiawan:ewsetiawan /home/ewsetiawan/.config/google-chrome -R
sudo rm -R /home/ewsetiawan/.config/google-chrome
```

Source:
[Chrome won't install or launch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010802)